# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function. How is the solution for getting the error?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I want to run my react application with firebase.I do not receive an error in the visual studio Code program. but in my web browser, applymiddaware(thunk.withextraargument ({getFirebase,getFirestore})) : TypeError: Object (...) is giving a function error.I wonder what is the solution?

index.js

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import {createStore, applyMiddleware,compose} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './store/rootReducer';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {getFirestore,reduxFirestore } from 'redux-firestore'
import {getFirebase,reactReduxFirebase} from 'react-redux-firebase'
import fbConfig from './config/fbConfig'

const store=createStore(rootReducer, 
    compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase,getFirestore})),
    reduxFirestore(),
    reactReduxFirebase()
    )
    );

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store ={store}></Provider>><App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "marioplan",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "firebase": "^7.8.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^3.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.12.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json file, I see that you installed version 3.1.1 of react-redux-firebase but you are creating the store using the synthax for older version ( virsion 2). you have to either downgrade react-redux-firebase to version 2 or create your store folowing v3 migration guide [here](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html). used similar synthax for react-redux-firebase 2.2.4 in the past.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'SDK_VERSION' of undefined.I did what you said, but he made a mistake.

Comment: try these two virsions like this:   npm i --save react-redux@5.1.1 react-redux-firebase@2.2.4 , if there is another issue , check if the virsions you are using are compatible.